# sed to replace string in file only displayed but not executed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to find all files with certain name (Myfile.txt) that do not contain certain string (my-wished-string) and then do a sed in order to do a replace in the found files. I tried with:

`find . -type f -name "Myfile.txt" -exec grep -H -E -L "my-wished-string" {} + | sed 's/similar-to-my-wished-string/my-wished-string/'`

But this only displays me all files with wished name that miss the "my-wished-string", but does not execute the replacement. Do I miss here something?

Answer (score 0):

With a for loop and invoking a shell.

```
find . -type f -name "Myfile.txt" -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    grep -H -E -L "my-wished-string" "$f" &&
    sed -i "s/similar-to-my-wished-string/my-wished-string/" "$f"
done' sh {} +
```

---

You might want to add a `-q` to `grep` and `-n` to `sed` to silence the printing/output to `stdout`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by constructing two stacks; the first containing the files to search, and the second containing negative hits, which will then be iterated over to perform the replacement.

```
find . -type f -name "Myfile.txt" > stack1
while read -r line;
do
[ -z $(sed -n '/my-wished-string/p' "${line}") ] && echo "${line}" >> stack2
done < stack1

while read -r line;
do
sed -i "s/similar-to-my-wished-string/my-wished-string/" "${line}"
done < stack2
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out this option

Comment: That is my pleasure.  I personally do not like stacking lots of parameters into the find command itself; I find it much easier if I actually seperate things out and do one step at a time.  Other people might call it inefficient, but I need to write code that I am able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

With some versions of `sed`, you can use `-i` to edit the file.  But don't pipe the list of names to sed, just execute `sed` in the find:

```
find . -type f -name Myfile.txt -not -exec grep -q "my-wished-string" {} \; -exec sed -i 's/similar-to-my-wished-string/my-wished-string/g' {} \;
```

Note that any file which contains `similar-to-my-wished-string` also contains the string `my-wished-string` as a substring, so with these exact strings the command is a no-op, but I suppose your actual strings are different than these.

Comment: Thx for one-liner! and yes, I use different strings (was bad example from my side)

Comment: only thing; "-not" did not work in my case (I use grep -L  instead)